# Finding Boot Signature in .dd image

Tags: boot, signature, computer-forensics

i am working on digital forensics assignment. I need help on what is the boot signature in this image. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: The boot signature here is in bytes 510 and 511 (the last 2 bytes of a 512 byte sector). Those are the bytes `55 AA`. The boot signature is the byte `0x55` followed by `0xAA`

Comment: @MichaelPetch, Thank you!;)